# Is there a way to search podcasts in collection?

Tags: search, podcast

Is there a way to search podcasts "in collection" on the phone?

If you've got a load of TED talks (I've got 69 listed) it'd be nice to be able to search them.

Shown below is a screen from Google image search just to show the kind of screen I'm looking at. Only in my case the list goes on and on and on.

Searching all podcasts, or all audio (I haven't got any audio except for speech/podcasts) or searching just within the TED feed, any of those would be equally fine as a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the Zune client, but I havent found a way to do it on the device alone. Here is a screenshot that shows my search results. Notice the FROM YOUR COLLECTION list.

[image]

Comment: thanks, the particular itch i wanted to scratch was to find out if i had a particular TED talk on my phone right now, and i'm nowhere near my zune/desktop. but thanks your answer might help me in future.